# Get user feedback on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am building an application for Windows Phone. Every time the user does something inside the application, I write stuff about that action on a "log" .txt file. It also logs the crashes and the unhandled exceptions.

How can I get the .txt from the user so that I can find and resolve possible errors / exceptions?

I dont want to use the email composer task since the user may edit or modify it before sending it to me. I know I can encode / encrypt the data but im looking for something else.

Is there any other way to do that?

What I have in my mind is a button that when the user clicks it it connects to the internet and uploads the .txt on some ftp server. or something similar

Comment: I know that u don't want to use the composer task but you should have a look at Little Watson: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andypennell/archive/2010/11/01/error-reporting-on-windows-phone-7.aspx It works pretty well with my apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need your own server for that and after you can use http connexion.
Or if you want something very easy, just put something like Flurry or [Bugsense](http://www.bugsense.com/features) (free solution) on your application.

Comment: What about the ftp solution that I mentioned? Since its pretty easy to create an ftp server.

Comment: I think it's okay but you need to put your ftp identification on your project it may be not very safe.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll check out Bugsense since its free but if I come up with another solution that would be great. I dont want to rely on third parties. Anyway, thanks again!

Comment: What is a `http connexion` exactly?